# Ajax generated content, unable to hide when onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

HTML Code: (Dynamic Generated by ajax).

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" image-data="imagedata" name-data="name data" artist-data="artist data" country-data="in" id="1252785363" onclick="ajax($(this));return false;">Add Album</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary" image-data="imagedata" name-data="name data" artist-data="artist data" country-data="in" id="1252985363" onclick="ajax($(this));return false;">Add Album</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary" image-data="imagedata" name-data="name data" artist-data="artist data" country-data="in" id="1256985363" onclick="ajax($(this));return false;">Add Album</div>
```

Each DIV has unique ID!

Javascript:

```
function ajax($this) {
  var id = $this.attr("id");
  var image_data = $this.attr("image-data");
  var name_data = $this.attr("name-data");
  var artist_data = $this.attr("artist-data");
  var country_data = $this.attr("country-data");

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "URL to Call",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
      image: image_data,
      artist: artist_data,
      name: name_data,
      country: country_data,
      id: id
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $(id).hide();
      alert(id);
    }
  });
}
```

Its return the response, its alert the ID, but somehow i am unable to find, i try `$(id).css('display', 'none');` , toggle but no luck!

If possible please let me know the solution!

Comment: what does alert(id) return?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi its return the value of DIV id!

Comment: Off topic: Look into replacing your onclick handlers with event listeners. jQuery is beautiful for that, and your markup becomes much cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `#` prefix to select an ID.

```
$("#" + id).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks you man! answer will be accepted in next 6 minute :)

P.S: I am not good with javascript (Jquery) still learning!

Answer (score 3):

The `id` attribute you are reading does not contain the `#` selector, which JQuery wants when you search for the element.

If instead you use `$("#" + id).hide();` I think you will get the result you are looking for.